# Would it be a good idea to be able to display Tag Badges on Your CV

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, tag-badges

On the Jobs page you can select which tags are displayed against you when you are in the top n%.

I think it would be a good idea to be able to pick tag *badges* as well. Some of these (particularly gold ones) take a lot of work to get and so carry some kudos with them.